# Dynamically generate <Image> tag [React-Native]

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to render a view (which contains question and options).If the question has multiple images in it,how can i generate image tag accordingly.
for eg:

`question: what is the value of <Image>21xtp-1.png</Image> 
and <Image>21xtp-2.png</Image> ?`

I want to replace that Image tags with  tag in react native.
i can do it like

`<Text>what is the value of <Image source={{uri:../images/21xtp.png-1}}/> and <Image source={{uri:../images/21xtp.png-1}}/> </Text>`

but how can i place the tags acoording to the number of images in a question which can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @atitpatel mentioned was correct,but i failed to get the image from rendering because i was getting it using file path

**USING FILEPATH :**

```
file:///data/user/0/com.example/files/21xtp.png
```

So,if any one across come up with same issue .Don't forget to add `height` and `width` as style to image tag.

```
for(i=0; i<imageUriArray.length;i++){
return(
 <Image source={{uri : imageUriArray[i]}} style=
  {{height:300,width:300}}/>
 )
}
```

And **USING HTTP**

if you are getting file using http ,make sure you add `https` to the uri

```
for(i=0; i<imageUriArray.length;i++){
 return(
 <Image source={{uri : "https://www.example.com/123.png"}} style=
   {{height:300,width:300}}/>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't understand the question very properly. But seems like you want to dynamically render the images depending upon your data.

Let's say your image uris are stored in an array. Then you can write your code something like :

```
for(i=0; i<imageUriArray.length;i++){
   return(
     <Image source={{uri : imageUriArray[i]}}/>
   )
}
```

Comment: if i give require('imagepath') it works,but if i call uriArray no image is displayed.